# pointer arithmetic with pointer to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to do pointer arithmetic with a pointer to array, but I get a wrong value since I can't dereference the pointer properly.
Here is the code:

```
  #include "stdlib.h"
  #include "stdio.h"

  int main()
  {
  int a[] = {10, 12, 34};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
      printf("%d", a[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  int (*b)[3] = &a;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
      printf("%d", *(b++));
  }
 printf("\n");

  return 0;
  }
```

In the second for I can't get to print the correct value.

It doesn't work even if I write

```
printf("%d", *b[i]);
```

I'd like to see how to print correctly using the b++ and the b[i] syntax.

Comment: `printf("%d", *(b++));` --> `printf("%d", (*b)[i]);`

Comment: Replacing **++i** with **i++** should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
printf("%d\n", *( *b+i ));
```

// * b + i will give you each consecutive address starting at address of the first element a[0].
// The outer '*' will give you the value at that location.

instead of:

```
printf("%d", *(b++));
```

Comment: I'll select this has the correct answer but I want more explanations, why this doesn't work, and what it's doing? `printf("%d\n", *( *b++ ));` And why this one works: `printf("%d\n", *( *b)); b = *b + 1;` with a warning: `incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int (*)[3]' from 'int *`

Comment: *b de-references 'b' i.e. it gives you what is at the address pointed to by 'b', say address location 1000. When you do a '+ 1' to it, you are pointing to the next element from location 1000.  A *b++ will cause 'b' to be incremented i.e. the pointer's address itself will be incremented, not what the pointer is pointing to.  Also ... for 1-Dimensional arrays, try using just int *b = a; and use int (*b)[3] = a; for 2-Dim arrays e.g. a[2][3].

Comment: when I write `*b++` I'm incrementing b why? It is the same as b++? When I do `b = *b + 1` I'm incrementing what b points to. To use the postfix ++ I should write: `(*b)++`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `b` to be a pointer to arrays of 3 integers and you have initialized it with address of `a`.

```
int (*b)[3] = &a;
```

In the first loop you will print the first element of `a` array but then you will move `3*sizeof(int)` and trigger undefined behavior trying to print whatever there is.

To print it correctly:

```
int *b = a;
// int *b = &a[0];    // same thing
// int *b = (int*)&a; // same thing, &a[0] and &a both points to same address,
                      // though they are of different types: int* and int(*)[3]
                      // ...so incrementing they directly would be incorrect,
                      // but we take addresses as int* 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    printf("%d", (*b++));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need `int *b = a;`? Or does C allow the conversion `int *b = &a;`?

Comment: I don't think they are both correct. Your compiler just happens not to emit an error. I get `array_ptr2.c:9:10: error: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type  'int (*)[3]' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` with clang, compiled in C99 mode.

Comment: @juanchopanza True. `int* b = a;` and `int *b = (int*)&a;` are both correct, but not `int *b = &a;`

Answer (score 0):

gcc will complain about the formatting in the second for loop: it will tell you `format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *`

your assignment of a to b should look like this:

```
int *b = a
```